# Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb, remote-debugging, gdbserver

I am using eclipse and arm-linux-gnueabihf to compile, deploy and debug remote c++ applications on BeagleBone Black. When debbuging, I am getting following error:

```
warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will be unable to debug shared library initializers
and track explicitly loaded dynamic code.
No source file named /home/lukasz/Programy/eclipsework/OvenCore/src/OvenCore.cpp.
No line 87 in file "/home/lukasz/Programy/eclipse_linux_projects/OvenCore/src/OvenCore.cpp".
No source file named /home/lukasz/Programy/eclipsework/OvenCore/src/OvenCore.cpp.
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for 7 libraries, e.g. /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0.
Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
```

In the project properties->c/c++ genaral->patchs and symbols I have set the include and lib pathes to the cross compiller directories. Am I supposed to do something more? I would aprichiate all help.

Comment: Could you provide links to the BeagleBone Black image and cross compilers you're using?

Comment: The image is the standard one, the cross compiller is https://releases.linaro.org/14.04/components/toolchain/binaries/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2014.04_linux.tar.xz